# How to arrange return content in pywin32

Tags: python, printing, pywin32

I have few lines of code to send job to my printer using `pywin32` but when i send this command the content for the new line it doesn't appear on it row on the paper `(newline)` after printing but continue to follows the first row the content.
When i print this to the terminal it print like what i desire but not when i send the job to the printer.
[image: image description of the printed result]

Have been searching on this site on how am going to arrange my content when sending it printed but to no avail.

```
import win32con
import win32print
import win32ui


def text():
    rows = (("PETER PAUL", "MALE", "100000"), ("MARGARET ", "FEMALE", "1000"), ("MICHAEL JORDAN", "MALE", "1"),("AGNES", "FEMALE", "200"))
    return '\r\n'.join('{:20} {:8} {}'.format(*row) for row in rows)


print(text())


def printer():
    dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
    printername = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    dc.CreatePrinterDC(printername)
    dc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS)
    scale_factor = 20
    dc.StartDoc('Win32print ')
    pen = win32ui.CreatePen(0, int(scale_factor), 0)
    dc.SelectObject(pen)
    font = win32ui.CreateFont({
    "name": "Lucida Console",
    "height": int(scale_factor * 10),
    "weight": 400,
})
    dc.SelectObject(font)
    dc.TextOut(scale_factor * 72, -1 * scale_factor * 72, text())
    dc.EndDoc()


printer()
```

Comment: `TextOut()` doesn't know about carriage returns. You need to do a separate `TextOut()` call for each line, calculating the coordinates as you go. This really has nothing to do with Python or PyWin32. You're calling the Windows API.

Comment: @BoarGules thanks for the respond on that but please can demonstrate what you meant call for each line or if the is any link you can paste for me have a look at it.

Comment: The first two parameters of  the call are the x and y coordinates of the corner of the box you are putting text in. You have to recompute x by scale_factor * 10 each time you output a new line.

Comment: don't understand have to look at the win32  documention  again to understand the x and y coordinate

Comment: can you write short code for that so i can work around to achieve that

Comment: @CristiFati i this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390367/printing-text-on-top-of-jpeg-or-png-image-in-python-with-pywin32?noredirect=1#comment87796836_50390367) can you help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) doesn't have an official doc (or at least I couldn't find any), so I'll be using the 2<sup>nd</sup> best thing available: [ActiveState](https://docs.activestate.com) (I could only find references for the ancient *Python2.4*, but generally they are OK)

[[ActiveState.Docs]: PyCDC.TextOut](https://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyCDC__TextOut_meth.html) wraps [[MS.Docs]: TextOutW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textoutw). The function doesn't handle ***\r\n*** (and definitely other special *char*s) like *print* does (the doc doesn't say anything about this), but instead it just ignores them (it doesn't have the concept of **line**). That means that in order to achieve *print* - like functionality, the user is responsible for outputting each line individually (of course at a different *Y* coordinate - to avoid outputting on top of the previous one).

To better illustrate the behavior, I created an example (based on your code).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time
import win32ui
import win32con
import win32print


def get_data_strings():
    rows = (("PETER PAUL", "MALE", "100000"), ("MARGARET ", "FEMALE", "1000"), ("MICHAEL JORDAN", "MALE", "1"),("AGNES", "FEMALE", "200"))
    return ["{:20} {:8} {}".format(*row) for row in rows]


def text():
    return "\r\n".join(get_data_strings())


def paint_dc(dc, printer_dc, paint_each_string=True):
    scale_factor = 20
    if printer_dc:
        x_y = 100, 0  # TopLeft of the page. In order to move away from the point, X increases to positives, while Y to negatives
        font_scale = 10
        y_direction_scale = -1  # For printers, the Y axis is "reversed"
        y_ellipsis = -100
    else:
        x_y = 100, 150  # TopLeft from wnd's client area
        font_scale = 1
        y_direction_scale = 1
        y_ellipsis = 100

    font0 = win32ui.CreateFont(
        {
            "name": "Lucida Console",
            "height": scale_factor * font_scale,
            "weight": 400,
        })
    font1 = win32ui.CreateFont(
        {
            "name": "algerian",
            "height": scale_factor * font_scale,
            "weight": 400,
        })
    fonts = [font0, font1]
    dc.SelectObject(font0)
    dc.SetTextColor(0x0000FF00) # 0BGR
    #dc.SetBkColor(0x000000FF)
    dc.SetBkMode(win32con.TRANSPARENT)
    if paint_each_string:
        for idx, txt in enumerate(get_data_strings()):
            dc.SelectObject(fonts[idx % len(fonts)])
            dc.TextOut(x_y[0], x_y[1] + idx * scale_factor * font_scale * y_direction_scale, txt)
    else:
        dc.TextOut(*x_y, text())
    pen = win32ui.CreatePen(0, 0, 0)
    dc.SelectObject(pen)
    dc.Ellipse((50, y_ellipsis, *x_y))


def paint_wnd(wnd, paint_each_string=True):
    dc = wnd.GetWindowDC()
    paint_dc(dc, False, paint_each_string=paint_each_string)
    wnd.ReleaseDC(dc)


def paint_prn(printer_name, paint_each_string=True):
    printer_name = printer_name or win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
    dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
    dc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
    dc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS)
    dc.StartDoc("Win32print")
    #dc.StartPage()
    paint_dc(dc, True, paint_each_string=paint_each_string)
    #dc.EndPage()
    dc.EndDoc()


def main():
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    print(text())
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if sys.argv[1] == "window":
            paint_func = paint_wnd
            paint_func_dc_arg = win32ui.GetForegroundWindow()
        else:
            paint_func = paint_prn
            paint_func_dc_arg = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        paint_func = paint_prn
        paint_func_dc_arg = None
    paint_func(paint_func_dc_arg, paint_each_string=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- I don't have a printer attached (actually I do, but I don't want to print smth every time I run the program), so I'm using current window (*cmd*) *HDC* to output data (therefore, I removed the printer specific code)
- I structured the code a bit, added functions so it's modular
- I split your *text* functionality in 2:

  - *get_data_strings* - which returns a list of strings where each is the textual representation of one row from *rows* (It would be nicer to make it a *generator*, but I don't want to overcomplicate things)
  - *text* - that simply joins them (to be consistent with existing interface)
- Regarding graphics (*GDI*):

  - *TextOut* doesn't care about the pen, it only uses the selected font, background color (`dc.SetBkColor`), and text color (`dc.SetTextColor`), but I left it there and drew an ellipse (just for fun)
  - The integer arguments (based on *scale_factor*) are way out of line (too big - at least for my *HDC*), so I reduced them to more decent values
  - As you can see, I'm outputting each string individually (and also increment its *Y* by *scale_factor* - which it's also the font height). I also kept the old way (printing the whole string) there, you just need to set *print_each_string* argument to *False* to achieve the same result that you did
- `time.sleep` is required there because outputting to *HDC* happens a lot faster than *print* (because of buffering), so even if according to code it happens after *print*, actually its effect happens before, and *print* "pushes" the window content (including our graphic output) up, so when the graphic output will go outside the visible area, it will be invalidated and that zone will be repainted, making it disappear. 
  I'm not sure if I made myself clear, but once you'll play with the code (comment the line), you'll see what I mean
- Some of the stuff from code might not work (or work differently) with the printer, as it's a different type of device
- There's an alternative: using [[ActiveState.Docs]: PyCDC.DrawText](https://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyCDC__DrawText_meth.html) (wrapper over [[MS.Docs]: DrawText function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext)), which is able to deal with multiline strings, but you'd still need to do some calculations in order to adjust the drawing *RECT* (I didn't feel like playing with that function too)

**Output**:

[image: Program Output]

***@EDIT0***:

Added some printer specific functionality. Also, changed the behavior:

- Without arguments, the app prints to the default printer
- The 1<sup>st</sup> argument (if given) can be a printer name or "*window*" (for initial behavior)
- The way *HDC*s work is different:

  - For printers the scaling is much higher (~10 times) - I assume it's because the window *HDC* works directly with pixels, while for printer *HDC* also takes *DPI* into account
  - Also, going top->bottom the *Y* coordinates increase in absolute values, but are **negative**
  - I put some values that work *OK* for "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer, but I assume that those values should be set accordingly by reading printer properties

**Output**:

[image: Img1]

***@EDIT1***:

- Added "multiple font support" as requested in a comment

Comment: thanks for this but am trying to send the job to printer using `win32print` but when i edit your code it doesn't print.

Comment: if you don't have printer at your end you can use `pdf` writer or `xps` writer test that

Comment: Yes, I'll update the answer with printer functionality.

Comment: thanks for this but please can you comment the code for me to understand bettter

Comment: i want to leave spaces at top and at left hand side but am able to do the left hand side i think if you comment it i can work around it.

Comment: Then you must supply different values for `x_y = 100, 0`. Increase the 1st value (200, 300, ...) so that the text moves to the right, and the increase 2nd value (in **negative** numbers: -100, -200, ...) so that the text moves towards the bottom.

Comment: to add `string` to be printed i have to do ` dc.TextOut(scale_factor * 42, -1 * scale_factor * 42, 'LAS PYTHON ')` to send it to the printer how can i specify font type for it without using the `lucida console`

Comment: You have to create a font and make it active. I don't know what happens if you don't, I'd guess that some default font is being used. All the operations that require a font, use the active one. If you need more than one font, create them, store in a list and when you want to switch between them just use `SelectObject`.

Comment: i did this `font1 = win32ui.CreateFont({"name": "algerian","height": int(scale_factor * 10),"weight": 400,}) ` then parsed it to another `dc.SelectObject(font1)` after that it picks the first one.

Comment: Most likely, you somehow select the same font. I was able to write with both fonts. After `dc.SelectObject(font1)` all `dc.TextOut` should use `font1`. I printed the 4 records intemitently with 2 fonts with no problem.

Comment: Please can you post what you did as comment or update it to the answer

Comment: Updated the code, but note that I'm not going to post any other updates since they are beyond the question's scope.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again when i have a lot of `tuple` and print through printer `A4 printer` it prints the first page then 
leave the rest of the records instead of picking another paper again and print the rest of records it doesn't do that. Always prints records which fit on one paper and leave the paper have tried on a lot printers same result.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what's required for a printer to work with multiple pages (I assumed that it will automatically get to the next page when the current one is full). What I can suggest as a workaround, is split your records in batches that fit in one page, and print them sequentially.